# How to go back to month after selecting day in Calendar View webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-rest-api, jquery-ajax

I have select Day from month but not get any button to go back to month view.
As shown below.

How we can get month after selecting days as shown in second screenshot.

Their is no button to go back to month view.

[image]

I need to go back to month view after selecting day.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change scope by clicking buttons under Calendar tab on the ribbon.
 [image]
If the Calendar tab does not appear, click on the calendar, then it should display.

Comment: Is it possible using jquery or any enjection in webpart? I am not able to see tab on the ribbon because i have added event calender in web part page.

Comment: Click on the calendar on the page, the tab would show. Or you can refresh page, check if it appears.